# rails-controller-testing Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rubygems

I just pulled my app up to edge rails. I've fixed most compatibility issues, however tests are now giving errors like this:

```
NoMethodError: assigns has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it,
    add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile.
```

The first time this occurred, I added `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to my `Gemfile` in the `:test` group and ran `bundle`. According to this process, the gem is now installed at version `0.0.3`, however I am getting the same errors. How do I resolve them?

Comment: can you please attach your gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  [:controller, :view, :request].each do |type|
    config.include ::Rails::Controller::Testing::TestProcess, :type => type
    config.include ::Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions, :type => type
    config.include ::Rails::Controller::Testing::Integration, :type => type
  end
end
```